# android slidingmenu and expandablelistview not working

Tags: android, expandablelistview, slidingmenu

---Updated below---

I am having a problem with showing an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)(ELV) inside a [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) fragment. The fragment is loaded fine, and if I use a ListView there are no problems. I have implemented a custom adapter to load the view for the groups and child items, and everything works as expected when the ELV is loaded in a normal activity.

I have been debugging it for ages and the actual ELV is drawn (I set the background to all red, and it is shows where I expected it), but the groups and child elements are not drawn. All relevant methods in the adapter is called when the activity with the slidingmenu is loaded (like getGroupView).
Can anyone help me in getting the actual groups and children to show inside the SlidingMenu?

This is my ELV in the layout XML:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/trackermenutypes_explist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:transcriptMode="disabled"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
/>
```

Methods in the adapter to get view:

```
   @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_typegroup, null);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_typegroup_name)).setText(mTypeGroups.get(groupPosition).getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "Returning GroupView for group \"" + mTypeGroups.get(groupPosition).getName() + "\"");
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_type, null);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_type_name)).setText(mGroupedTypes.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "Returning ChildView for type \"" + mGroupedTypes.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getName() + "\"");
        return convertView;
    }
```

My fragments onActivityCreated method (with the working ListView commented out in the bottom):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = (TrackerActivity) getActivity();
    //lTypesList = getListView();
    lExpList = (ExpandableListView)mContext.findViewById(R.id.trackermenutypes_explist);
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);

    mTypeGroupDataSource = new TypeGroupDataSource(mContext);
    mTypeGroupDataSource.open();
    mTypeGroups = mTypeGroupDataSource.getAllTypeGroups();

    mTypeDataSource = new TypeDataSource(mContext);
    mTypeDataSource.open();
    mTypes = mTypeDataSource.getTypesOfClub(DataService.DEFAULT_CLUB_ID);
    mTypes.addAll(mTypeDataSource.getTypesOfClub(mPrefs.getLong(DataService.PREFS_CLUB_ID, -1)));

    TypeAdapter typeAdapter = new TypeAdapter(mContext, mTypeGroups, mTypes);
    lExpList.setAdapter(typeAdapter);

    lExpList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            mContext.updateCurrentType(id);
            mContext.getSlidingMenu().toggle();
            return true;
        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG, "Expanding " + typeAdapter.getGroupCount() + " groups");
    for (int i = 0; i < typeAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++){
        lExpList.expandGroup(i);
    }
    //TODO Implement "Add Type" feature
    /*ArrayAdapter<TypeData> typeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<TypeData>(mContext, R.layout.listitem_type, R.id.listitem_type_name, mTypes);
    setListAdapter(typeAdapter);

    lTypesList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long id) {
            mContext.updateCurrentType(position);
            mContext.getSlidingMenu().toggle();
        }
    });*/
}
```

---UPDATE---
I figured out a way to get it to draw the groups and items, by making my fragment a ListFragment and using setList instead. This is kind of a hack, since now e.g. the setAdapter does not work with my custom BaseExpandableListAdapter. And when I call it on the actual list (from findViewByID), it does not react to the touch events. So now I have a beautiful list, that cannot be used. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find any answers on getting the ExpandableListView to show in the SlidingMenu without "hacking" it and using a ListFragment - which results in not being able to use the stadndard setAdapter on the fragment to set the ExpandableListAdapter. Perhaps an ExpandableListFragment would solve the problem if available.

The updated bug with no reaction to touch events was my own fault - I was returning false in the adapters isChildSelectable method.